# How to stop a new console window from starting when building or debugging a project in Visual studio for Mac Professional?

Tags: mac, visual-studio

Everytime I build a project or debug, a new console window pops up with functions runtime information and program output. 
I want to have the output terminal, debug console, build information etc. in the same visual studio window. I found similar questions but the solution were for the older version of visual studio and my version of visual studio did not have those menu options (No Preview tab or Tools -> options) . 
The visual studio version that I have is a Visual Studio for Mac Professional, version 8.1.5 (build 9).